# SQL Month to date and Quarter to date

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to analyze some numbers and look at them on a month-to-date and quarter-to-date basis.

The end goal is to be able to compare where we stood at certain points in time by months and quarters across all time.

For example, my raw data might look like this:

```
date               metric
10-01-2014           100
10-02-2014           100
10-03-2014           100
11-01-2014           100
11-02-2014           100
11-03-2014           100
12-01-2014           100
12-02-2014           100
12-03-2014           100
```

And I need to get it like this:

```
date                      metric       month-to-date       q-to-date
10-01-2014           100                100                     100
10-02-2014           100                200                     200
10-03-2014           100                300                     300
11-01-2014           100                100                     400
11-02-2014           100                200                     500
11-03-2014           100                300                     600
12-01-2014           100                100                     700
12-02-2014           100                200                     800
12-03-2014           100                300                     900
```

Below is the code I've done to. It gets a rolling 30-day avg of this metric. I think this is conceptually similar to what I'm trying to do, but different enough to have me a bit stumped.

```
select 
        date,
        city,
        metric,
        avg(metric)
                        over(partition by city
                        order by date
                        range between interval '29 days' preceding and CURRENT ROW) as metric_30day_avg
```

Please let me know if you need any more details from my end. I'd be happy to help others help me learn to fish.

Comment: Is there an id or timestamp column as well? (Need to distinguish between rosw from same date.)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: There is no id or timestamp column. In fact, we store our dates as integers, so the date I showed is after I would have converted it...

Comment: This is using MySQL.

Comment: Over partition by with mysql?mysql deosnt have that syntax

Comment: Mihai - Yeah, I know. That's what I know from using Vertica. But this work is in MySQL, which is what I need help with.